# Enable-SPFeature not working

Tags: powershell, deployment, feature-activation

I am using PowerShell script to deploy and activate a feature in the same script. Everything works fine and I can see my feature in the Sharepoint Root folder (14 hive).

I run it using Farm Admin.

My feature is Site Collection level and when I run the following line for root collection level.

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity MyFeaure -Url http://br22:5646
```

I get the following error:

> Enable-SPFeature : The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in
>   a Site level defined by

Content of feature.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Feature xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"; 
        Title="AUP Site Provisioning Feature" 
        Description="This feature will Create Custom List(s), Views and Share Point Groups for AUP Accelerator site" 
        Id="4e09be48-d2fc-49c6-9643-4f84aaa18806" 
        ReceiverAssembly="Tax.Accelerators.AUP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=73438e84b4622991"  
        ReceiverClass="Tax.Accelerators.AUP.AUP_Tax_FeatureEventReceiver" 
        Scope="Site"> 
    <ElementManifests> 
        <ElementManifest Location="ChangeStatusRibbonElement\Elements.xml" />
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste your deployment script ? My bet is that you miss a call to [install-spfeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607825.aspx). Also, do you use a wsp solution package ?

Comment: ya i use .wsp package and i follow Add-SPSolution,Install-SPSolution and then Enable-SPFeature statements.

Comment: can you paste the content of feature.xml ? Does `Get-SPFeature -Url http://here` returns your feature ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="AUP Site Provisioning Feature" Description="This feature will Create Custom List(s), Views and Share Point Groups for AUP Accelerator site" Id="4e09be48-d2fc-49c6-9643-4f84aaa18806" ReceiverAssembly="Tax.Accelerators.AUP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=73438e84b4622991" ReceiverClass="Tax.Accelerators.AUP.AUP_Tax_FeatureEventReceiver" Scope="Site"> <ElementManifests> <ElementManifest Location="ChangeStatusRibbonElement\Elements.xml" /></ElementManifests>
</Feature>

Comment: I edited your post to include the xml file. It's far more readable tha in the comment.

Comment: And what does the call the Install-SPFeature does ?

Comment: Steve, Install-SPFeature fails and no effect...still remains unchanged ..

Answer (score 5):

This error mostly occurs when you go wrong with the name of the feature. Activate it using GUID instead, should help!

Comment: Also, if the solution is not installed. Try running the  command after Install-SPSolution has run completely...

Answer (score 1):

Jay,

Can you see this feature on Site Settings>> Site Collection Fetaures (OR Site Features).
If not then you have to install using below command.

Have you install feature using this script ?

```
     Install-SPFeature -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\MyCustomFeature\feature.xml"
```

then run

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity MyFeaure -Url http://br22:5646
```

Comment: Yes , I can see that in Site Collection Feature list but not Activated mode..

Comment: Can u activate manually ?

Comment: ya i can activate manually, but only thing is that my feature contains 2 timer jobs, so if i activate manually it will be activated with other contnents but it will not allow me to create those timer jobs. I think thats whole logic behind running PS to deploy it..

Comment: Try this Jay, Enable-SPFeature -Identity ChangeStatusRibbonElement -Url "siteurl"

Comment: guruji ....feature enabled is not done...and harassing me .

Comment: this feature is site collection level right ?

Comment: change feature scope to Farm then try beacuse you feature contains Timer Job.

Comment: run feature activation code in                 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){
                 });

Answer (score 1):

I had this when trying to activate the feature on the App server instead of the Web server on our farm.

Answer (score 0):

write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Feature xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"; 
        Title="AUP Site Provisioning Feature" 
        Description="This feature will Create Custom List(s), Views and Share Point Groups for AUP Accelerator site" 
        Id="4e09be48-d2fc-49c6-9643-4f84aaa18806" 
        ReceiverAssembly="Tax.Accelerators.AUP, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=73438e84b4622991"  
        ReceiverClass="Tax.Accelerators.AUP.AUP_Tax_FeatureEventReceiver" 
        Scope="Site"> 
    <ElementManifests> 
        <ElementManifest Location="ChangeStatusRibbonElement\Elements.xml" />
        <ElementFile Location="Name of the file you want to copy on the site. "/>
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that when you ran Install-SPSolution you installed the solution to a specific web app which does not contain the site collection you are trying to activate the feature on.

For example if you installed the solution using the url `http://yoursite` and are now trying to activate the site on `http://yoursite:9999` this will not work. You need to run the `Install-SPSolution` command with the url `http://yoursite:9999`

If this is all good to go then the problem lies with the [Enable-SPFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803.aspx) command. To use the name of the feature like you are, the "name" must actually be the name of the feature folder and not the name of the feature itself. You can navigate to the `14\Template\Features` folder and see if you can find your feature. Use the name of the folder that your feature is located in. When using Visual Studio templates its defaulted to something like `PROJECT_FeatureName` instead of just FeatureName.

As another answer suggested, using the Guid instead is a pretty fail safe way of doing this as well. This can be found as the Id attribute of the Feature tag which in your case is `4e09be48-d2fc-49c6-9643-4f84aaa18806`