# Deploying a .wsp File with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, farm-solution

I am attempting to install a farm solution with a Jenkins job so I need to do everything through PowerShell. So with PowerShell scripts I can:

- Create a web application
- Create a site collection
- Deploy a custom master page

What I still need to do is (unless I am missing something):

- Deploy a solution
- Deploy visual web parts to the web part library

I can create an "Empty SharePoint 2013" project in Visual Studio, edit the appropriate files, and deploy it successfully through Visual Studio. When I go to the URL my solution should deploy to, everything works. But when I try to deploy through PowerShell, I get a different result. When I run the following PowerShell script:

```
# Deploy and Install Solution

# ---- CONFIGURATION BLOCK ----
$site = "http://sharepointpilot/"
# The file found at ($solutionPath + "\" + $solutionName) must be a WSP file
$solutionPath = "C:\SharePointPilot\dir\dir\bin\Debug"
$solutionName = "solution.wsp"

# ---- CODE ----
$web = Get-WebApplication -Site $site
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath ($solutionPath + "\" + $solutionName)
Install-SPSolution -Identity $solutionName -GACDeployment
```

It installs, but does not deploy correctly.

When I run:

```
# Print XML Format of Solution Information
stsadm -o enumsolutions
```

I get the following:

```
<Solutions Count="1">
   <Solution Name="solution.wsp">
      <Id>1b9fc6b2-1fb0-43b7-982e-5e0643800694</Id>
      <File>solution.wsp</File>
      <Deployed>TRUE</Deployed>
      <WebApplicationSpecific>FALSE</WebApplicationSpecific>
      <ContainsGlobalAssembly>TRUE</ContainsGlobalAssembly>
      <ContainsFullTrustBinAssembly>FALSE</ContainsFullTrustBinAssembly>
      <ContainsCodeAccessSecurityPolicy>FALSE</ContainsCodeAccessSecurityPolicy>
      <LastOperationResult>DeploymentSucceeded</LastOperationResult>
      <LastOperationTime>9/29/2016 6:46 PM</LastOperationTime>
   </Solution>
</Solutions>
```

When I go to the URL my solution is supposed to be deployed, I get a 404 error.

I did notice when deploying in Visual Studio it says "enabling features" in the output. I tried to research that, but it ended up going nowhere.

If you can offer any help at all, it would be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am seeing is the enabling feature part is missing. Solution deployment most 3 steps process

1. Add solution, which u did
2. Install solution, you already did
3. Now missing part is enabling the feature on your site collection. Use following code`Enable-SPFeature -Url "[Site Collection URL]" -Identity "solution identity "`

After enabling l, you will see it.

Comment: I am error with the provided command. The error is: "The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in a Site level defined by the Url http://sharepointpilot/." There are four options for the scope of the feature in Visual Studio. With "Farm" or "WebApplication" I get an error in Visual Studio. With "Site" or "Web" I get an error in PowerShell.

Comment: Is it site collection level feature or web application?

Comment: Can you see that feature on site collection settings page? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22832/enable-spfeature-not-working

Comment: I am new to SharePoint development, but I believe it should be a site collection level feature. It is a site template with three site page instances of the template created through an Elements.xml file.

Comment: No, I cannot see the feature on the site collection settings page.

Comment: Try this one https://www.google.com/amp/s/moonistahir.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/enable-spfeature-issue-the-feature-is-not-a-farm-level-feature/amp/